# How to determine whether audio is music or not

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I would like to listen to talkshows and newsreports from a certain radio station but not to their music.  How do I automate the process of detecting the music, and silencing the stream?

Currently my only solution is to turn down the volume manually, and then wait for a few minutes to see if the music is over.  I would like to automate this process if possible.

Comment: This is possible, to a degree, but not simple.  You need to run a FFT on the sound and analyze it's spectrum.  You might actually get a question accepted [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "What is music?" is a philosophical question that humans cannot answer, let alone machines programmed by humans.  You're better of checking for a change in sound signature, such as suddenly a wider spectrum is used, vs the sound of a voice or two.

Comment: What is music? What is love: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU-s2yWgEI8

Comment: @Brad: I'm talking about a nationwide radio broadcast context, so this might simplify the problem and help defining "music". I am not talking about evey kind of philosophical ways of defining music, but a certain subset of it called "commercial hits of the moment". I refuse to believe I am the first to wonder the question or that there is no previous work on the subject. I am just unable to fully use my non-native English to dig deeper into web search engines.

Comment: Don't break patents ;-) http://www.google.com/patents/US4441203

Comment: I found several approaches Googling "filter speech music". They are highly technical papers, probably only useful if you want to do programming. But maybe there's some references in these papers you can use.